# Making a spring for use in Unity

Tags: animation, armature, unity

I've created a spring animation using shape keys in Blender and I would like to import it to Unity. I can get the spring into Unity, but I can't get the animation. How do I get the animation to work in Unity?

Comment: What format are you exporting?

Comment: I've tried .fbx and .blend

Answer (score 1):

I believe this dude goes into that.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3CSUxATQVLw

> create resource folder in unity.
>
> set char origin and bone origin to the same locations.
>
> export char to that location
>
> unity should automatically import all animations, materials, and other important contents.